# Scan for Existence of Other Devices

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-direct, cell-broadcast

Is it possible to know how many devises are in a certain area? I'm just trying to passively count the number of people in a room and I was hoping that my phone could recognize them by WiFi, Bluetooth, cell or some other frequency. I don't actually need to connect - just want to get a count.

Comment: There are several [apps for sniffing and port-scanning](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sniffspoof) to identify devices on the network. But how would you make sure to only gather devices located in the same room – and not in front of the door or even further away? No such tool considers physical topology of your surroundings IMHO.

Comment: I'm not too concerned with the topography of the room / picking up people in the next room. I guess I threw that out there as an example, not a rule.Do you know if any of these apps are able to be embedded in another project as a jar file?

Comment: No. Android apps don't come "as a `.jar` file", but as `.apk` file. Though the file structure is comparable, I doubt they can be used that way.